# How to convert object array to nested object by using Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm working on data assembling in a Laravel project. The data I could get from sql query is like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ben"
  }
]
```

I want to convert it to something like this,

```
{
  "1":{
    "name": "John"
  },
  "2":{
    "name": "Ben"
  }
}
```

Anyway elegant way to do it?

Comment: any code before elegance?

Comment: @codekaizer I used groupBy('id')

Comment: Show your code in the question. You can [edit] your question. Comments are not for question details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`keyBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-keyby) collection method